# Is adding a Community Wiki to list scientific journal LaTeX classes of value?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I am interested in looking at and having access to the various LaTeX classes that exist for submitting manuscripts to scientific journals. Many are already on CTAN but there is no way to know to what extent they are. The reasons for my immediate personal interest is otherwise that it is

1. interesting to see the different LaTeX solutions used in these class files
2. valuable to build a list of such classes for submitting papers
3. valuable to get an overview of what is out there
4. valuable as background information since some classes have their own tags on TeX.sx

The major caveat that I can see is that it can get totally out of hand, might possibly require moderation, which is why I am posing the question here to get feedback on the interest in and feasibility of the venture.

Since I have not found anything on TeX.sx or elsewhere (other than with very localized in scope) I pose the question, is this something to set up as a Community Wiki question on TeX.sx?

Comment: What do you mean by templates?  The sample article files using the journal's Latex class?

Comment: I mean the LaTeX class provided by the journal. These are often perhaps sloppily referred to as templates, possibly a carryover from a Word-dito. I am sorry for the confusion have updated the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If such a question would be posted, it should have community wiki status, since it would be a community effort and would become a big list instead of having a "correct" answer.

In such a case there should be a kind of sorting, such as by publisher, or by style (article, proceedings, or even book styles).

But it's questionable if it would be really useful, besides for curiosity reasons.

- People who submit to journals will get the style from the publisher or their web site.
- People who don't submit to journal X don't need this specific style X with requirements and restrictions.

Nobody knows if a style is good or recommendable. For example, [Springer recommends to use eqnarray](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-springer/), even today.

So I don't really see a benefit in collection a list of links, where later some will probably become dead when the publisher modifies his web site.

And people should not look here for a journal template, they should go directly to the publisher to get the newest and recommended or required one, not one from CTAN, not from a TeX distribution, or where we would link from here. Even deep links to pages on publisher sites can stay valid while possibly becoming obsolete, such as when there's a newer revision and the publisher points to the newer one but doesn't replace or delete the old one.

Comment: It seems to me that a list of links is useful, especially if it might be maintained.   It would be pretty big: there are a lot of custom, one-journal class files out there.  Link rot rate is not bad for journals: usually the class files are accessible from the instructions to authors page, which is most often hosted by the publisher and at an unchanging URL. I know I've seen a few partial attempts to list class files for particular topic areas, though I can't recall where, just now.

Comment: I was given a template I supposed to use for a Springer thing. It defined its own sectioning commands that didn't deal very well with page breaks...